# Does the web.config file settings override IIS settings?

Tags: asp.net, iis

For example,

I can specify the session timeout in the web.config file by adding:

```
<system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="10"/>
</system.web>
```

Or I can configure the session timeout in IIS by going to the Application Configuration Options.

If they are both configured to different values, which one wins? And more specifically, do all other settings follow the same pattern?

---

**EDIT:** I don't see them being as one in the same. The web.config wins. And when I change the value in IIS, nothing gets written back to the web.config.

There's a definite disconnect between the settings in the web.config and the settings in IIS. I haven't read any good documentation on which one overrides the other. All I've observed is that the web.config wins. I thought someone else may have some more insight into this disparity.

Answer (score 12):

The one in web.config 'wins'.

Edit:
Basically when you edit settings from UI the changes are written back to web.config

Answer (score 5):

Settings configured in the IIS Manager are added to the root applicationHost.config file for your server (located in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config) as `<location path="your-site/subfolder">` elements.  Since settings in a web.config always override those in the applicationHost.config, if the same setting has one value in the IIS Manager and another in your web.config, the web.config value 'wins'.

Answer (score 5):

Too late to answer but may clear things up for future people who get here.

This [article](http://%20https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides) explains inheritance between `IIS` and `ASP.net` applications.

Quote from ***Tip 3: Understand how your Web.config inherits IIS configuration settings***

> Of course, server administrators don't necessarily want to allow any
>   application on the server to modify settings via Web.config, so there
>   are configurable policies in the ApplicationHost.config which state
>   whether individual applications can override settings.

This [post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/overridemodedefault-and-allowdefinition-attributes/ba-p/305415) explains the usage of two `ApplicationHost.config` attributes: `overrideModeDefault` and `allowDefinition`. Both of these attributes set whether and who can override `IIS` settings which are inside `ApplicationHost.config`.

Based on those two, we cannot say undoubtedly that `web.config` overrides `IIS`, if we are not aware about `ApplicationHost.config` entries.

Quote from: [Introduction to ApplicationHost.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig)

> Most IIS sections are locked down by default, using
>   overrideModeDefault="Deny" in the section.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides

Comment: With the `lock down` default settings in sections, one may find the configs in `web.config` not working as he assumes.

Answer (score 4):

They are one in the same.

Answer (score 0):

Session timeout:
web.config will override the session timeout setting of the IIS config tool
Only for ASP.NET apps...

For asp the opposite is true